# Javascript compression algorithm which compresses into strings?

Tags: javascript, compression

Hello I am a high school student who is new to coding and I am working on a science fair project. For my project I am required to use a compression algorithm, due to my lack of knowledge I am restricted to javascript. I found a compression algorithm in jslzjb but the algorithm compresses the message into a byte array when I need it in strings.

Is there a way to compress a message into strings using javascript, by the way I need the compression algorithm to be lossless.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can just convert your byte array into a string of some sort?

Comment: A simple way to handle your problem is to encode binary data using Base64, although this introduces an overhead of 33%.

Comment: I actually tried that, what would happen is I would use the toString function however all this would cause is an expansion of the array actually causing the message to actually get bigger in size. I also tried using base64 given by jslzjb it also resulted in the message increasing in size slightly.

Comment: That's just the nature of the beast. Why are you restricted to JS again?

Comment: I am new to coding, all I have learned is javascript. What I am looking for is a way of compressing into strings. Can I not do that in Javascript? Would I need to use a different language?

Comment: Yes, you can but you'll run into this problem you're having now. It'll be a lot easier if you use a language that read and write binary data. If you have enough time, you could try Python.

Comment: I had a new thought, I am thinking about using the base64 approach with a much larger string than I was using before. Then the overhead may not be as significant. If there is a way which anybody sees to improve this change in design please suggest.

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, just use a string that's very compressible (eg: has a lot of repeated information). I'm not sure this fits the spirit of the project, but it works in demonstrating that compression works.

Comment: I was planning on running the same message on a for loop, would that provide the necessary repetition.

Comment: if you mean you will use a for loop to create a string which is the same thing repeated, yeah that should help. If I were you, I would try jSEND. It's a plugin for the jQuery library. You can use the demo at http://jsend.org/demo/. as with the methods you've found so far, you'll find that there is a minimum length for the uncompressed string below which the size will actually increase, but you can use the demo to find the tipping point before you start coding

Comment: You see, there is a reason you can't find any script that compiles directly to a string. And the problem you are running into, that if you convert it into a string you get extra overhead, is exactly that reason. A string isn't efficient here and you can't get around that. So people do not use strings for this... Basically, when using bytes for this, you can use all 256 a byte can represent. If you use a string, this will always be less (how much less depending on what characters you use). Less possible combinations means a longer overall length...

Answer (score 2):

The following compression algorithm is written by Curto in Javascript, and works directly on streams :
https://github.com/pierrec/node-lz4