# Compress text data in javascript and send it via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I develop web application that supposed to communicate with server using jQuery/AJAX/JSON. Just was curious, is it possible to compress somehow text data before send it to server and extract it there? Are there any already implemented JavaScript compressors?

In other words, how to implement next scenario:

1. Compress text data on client side using JavaScript
2. Send compressed data to the server
3. Decompress data on the server side

any ideas?

Comment: By archive do you mean compress?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript compression algorithm which compresses into strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022437/javascript-compression-algorithm-which-compresses-into-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any compression algorithm written in JS will do, or look into setting compression settings in the HTTP headers of the requests you're sending.

Comment: actually I was interested to get names of any compression algorithms implemented on JavaScript :) Do you know any?

Comment: @AlexWheat: Given its age, any algorithm is.

Comment: Thanks for the replay anyway even if doesn't provide any useful information. The reason the question was to get some name of any JS library that supports compression. Some simple example of using the library and compression methods would be also appreciated.

Comment: @AlexWheat: We're a Q&A site, not a search engine. We can only give answers to actual, practical problems. Not knowing *what you want to do* won't get you anywhere on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AlexWheat There is a relevant library in the question this is essentially a duplicate of and if you look at the library project page on github it includes usage details and examples. All that being said, you would likely be better suited to use HTTP compression instead of overlapping custom compression for particular data.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson, that's exactly what I wanted to get. Thanks for this!